# PHP mail using sendmail instead of mail

Tags: php, email

I am working on a legacy system and found this line of code:

```
sendmail($to_name, $email, "Account Created", $message, "", "Details", $emailb", "Account Created", example@example.com");
```

I have only ever seen mail(); when sending out PHP mail. Where may the sendmail(); function be coming from?

Comment: may be, it is user defined function.

Comment: Nope, there is no user defined function with that name

Comment: Is it used like this `className::sendmail()`?

Comment: see here : https://github.com/jvjvjv/Sendmail

Comment: 10 to 1 it still is user defined, eg. coming from an include file :-) Check all available sources.

Comment: Or... you might incorporate a debug_print_backtrace() right after the sendmail() function call in that code and run it. The backtrace will display the call stack and where the called functions reside. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: @Werner - thanks, that helped me find it

Comment: @EmJay  Cool! Happy to help!